# how did git add itself to the PATH on OSX 10.6 ? It's not in bashrc or profile?

Tags: git, macos, bash, path

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set PATH and other environment variables?](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/how-do-i-set-path-and-other-environment-variables)

I recently installed git 1.7.4.4 via the installer from here http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/ (not via homebrew or stuff...) and found that it added itself to my $PATH.

I wonder, where did it do that?
I checked my ~/.bashrc and also /etc/bashrc and /etc/profile, nowhere is a line like 
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin

Out of curiosity, where did the git-installer put the change to the path??

Comment: [Related](http://superuser.com/questions/284342/how-do-i-set-path-and-other-environment-variables/284351#284351) (with good section on Mac OS X, that already contains both answers from OS).

Comment: I don't know about OSX, but on linux, your bash profile generally sources `/etc/profile`, which then sources `/etc/profile.d/*.sh`.

Comment: IMO this question isn't a duplicate. The OP knows how stuff is usually added to the PATH, but git does it in an unusual way. Jefromi is correct - in the `/etc/paths.d` directory, there is a file named `git` containing the path to the git binary.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look in `/etc/paths.d/`. If there is a file called `git`, this is how your `$PATH` is manipulated.

Since Leopard, there is an alternative method for manipulating the PATH by adding text files to `/etc/paths.d/` containing lines that will be appended to the PATH variable. Kind of simple, but it does cause issues if you aren't aware of it.

**EDIT:** There is also a corresponding `/etc/manpaths.d/`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's located in /etc/paths??

```
cat /etc/paths
```